# Разделение строки на массив

Tags: php

Вроде как все просто и работает:

```
$a = 'Тег1, тег2,тег3 без пробела';
print_r(explode(",", $a));
```

Выдает такое:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Тег1
    [1] =>  тег2
    [2] => тег3 без пробела
)
```

Все нормально, только необходимо избавиться от пробела в начале, в таких случаях, как в элементе [1]. Там пробел есть перед именем. Его бы убрать.. Вопрос - как? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такая функция [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). Она умеет удалять пробелы в начале и в конце. Просто в цикле нужно пробежаться и применить.

Но если хочется в одну строку, то можно применить preg_split

```
$a = 'Тег1, тег2,тег3 без пробела';
print_r(preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", trim($a)));
```

Этот код корректно  разберет строку, даже если запятая будет окружена пробелами с обеих сторон. trim нужен на тот случай, если есть пробелы в начале строки и/или в конце.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотя я не совсем понял, что за "/\s*,\s*/"

Comment: это [регулярные выражения](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). 

первый слеш и последний - это такой разделитель. как скобки.

`\s` - это любой пробельный символ.
`*` - в данном контексте говорит "от 0 до бесконечности". поэтому конструкция `\s*` - означает от нуля до бесконечности пробельных символов.

А запятая обозначает сама себя.

Answer (score 2):

Так это же элементарно!

```
$a = 'Тег1, тег2,тег3 без пробела';
$a =  array_map('trim', explode(",", $a));
var_export($a);
```

=

```
array (
  0 => 'Тег1',
  1 => 'тег2',
  2 => 'тег3 без пробела',
)
```